# How to allow incoming unicast UDP packets in Windows 10 Universal App?

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp, udp, windows-10

My DSLM camera can send liveview over unicast UDP via WiFi connection. There are two ways to connect.

- Setting camera into WiFi AP mode and connect Windows 10 device to it.
- Connect camera to WiFi AP common for Windows 10 device. Device can connect to AP as by WiFi as by wire.

UWP `DatagramSocket` class can receive unicast UDP packets only if connected Network is marked as **discoverable** in connection settings. Network can be set discoverable in different ways for wire (Ethernet menu) and for WiFi (WiFi menu). By default Windows 10 connects to new network as public connection with discovery option disabled.

Is it possible anyhow in UWP API to enable incoming unicast UDP traffic to specific port from camera in local network even if connection is **public**? I can set camera to use any port I want.

If that is not possible how to switch specific connection to private/discoverable using UWP API?

If neither is possible how to open Windows 10 settings for current connected adapter directly at the page with discoverability (same page with connection details)? For wired and wireless connections on Windows desktop or mobile.

Comment: The are few different types of UDP : Broadcast, Multicast, Regular (same as tcp without acks).  Broadcast and Multicast are usually blocked by routers and are only seen by the local subnet.  Regular UDP can connect like TCP going through routers.

Comment: It's not going through router both devices are in local network. In case of AP mode of camera there is no even separate device between Windows device and camera. Incoming Unicast UDP traffic to general use ports is blocked by default if network connection is marked as *Public* in Windows.

Comment: If it is being blocked then it must be by a Virus Checker or Firewall.  Not windows.  Unblock the ports in application that is blocking. Check existing routes in cmd.exe with >netstat -a

Comment: See : http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html

Comment: There is no any "Virus Checker" except built in Defender. 
There no other Firewall, just standard in Windows. And there is no difference if it's disabled.

Comment: ```netstat -a``` does not show anything related to my UDP port even if connected network is **private** and app receiving UDP without any problem.

Comment: Ok, after several hours I finally found. Even if device is in local network and not outside of NAT still UWP Application need ```Internet (Client & Server)``` capability to receive UDP from local network if it's connected as **Public**. There is no need switching Firewall off, at least Windows 10 default Defender.